# 2 RestTemplate, but no possibility to pick the second one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have 2 RestTemplate declared in a config file :

```
@Configuration
MyConfig {
  @Bean("restTemplate")
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, ApplicationContext ctx) {
// (...)
  }

  @Bean("noProxyRestTemplate")
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, ApplicationContext ctx) {
// (...)
  }
}
```

then, when I want to use the "no proxy" RestTemplate, I'm using :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("noProxyRestTemplate")
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

But let's say I don't put any qualifier to see where it conflicts : it picks the one with proxy without seeing there are 2 valid candidates.

What is happening here ? Why this default choice when I have no "@Primary" annotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"As a fallback Spring uses the property name as a default qualifier value." [source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire)

Defining the bean property name, in this case as restTemplate, Spring matches that to the RestTemplate implementation

Comment: Yes I know that, but it doesn't explain what is happening. It doesn't explain why @Bean("restTemplate") is picked as implementation instead of @Qualifier("noProxyRestTemplate"). There should be an error like this : "No unique bean of type [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2"

Comment: try to rename the first bean. Spring should throw the error.

Comment: Yes ? What name do u suggest ? what is wrong with this name ?

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. The correct sentence is : "As a fallback Spring uses the **property** name as a default qualifier value."